# Exporting data from excel to access-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to upload a dataset from excel to an access database using the following code.

However i keep getting the Run time error 3078- Application defined or object defined error. i am using the dao for this and have added the follwing references:

Microsoft office 16.0 access database engine object library,
Microsoft access 16.0 library.

i am unable to add the Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library (Name conflicts with existing module, project or object libary

here is the code:

```
Sub access_upload()

Dim strMyPath As String, strDBName As String, strDB As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long, lLastRow As Long, lFieldCount As Long
Dim daoDB As DAO.Database
Dim recSet As DAO.Recordset

strDBName = "Database8.accdb"
'presume to be in the same location as the host workbook:

 strMyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

 strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName
 Set daoDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(strDB)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 Set recSet = daoDB.OpenRecordset("Database8")

 lFieldCount = recSet.Fields.Count
 lLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lLastRow
 recSet.AddNew
 For n = 0 To lFieldCount - 1
 recSet.Fields(n).Value = ws.Cells(i, n + 1)
 Next n
 recSet.Update
 Next i

 recSet.Close
 daoDB.Close

 Set daoDB = Nothing
 Set recSet = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Please let me know what i am missing here. Thanks!

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Set recSet = daoDB.OpenRecordset("Database8")     'This line

Comment: And is your table called Database8?

Comment: my access database name is Database8

Comment: Yup, but in your `OpenRecordset`, you need to enter the table name you want to insert the data into, not your database name

Comment: Yes i did that, and it is proceeding beyond that step, but now i am getting the same error on the step in the for loop:    recSet.Fields(n).Value = ws.Cells(i, n + 1)

Comment: That's probably because you haven't set up your table properly to receive the data you're sending it. A table isn't an Excel worksheet.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how to set up the table? I am new to access and vba and still learning the ropes

Comment: @SQL_APPRENTICE Are the fields in your table set to an appropriate data type? E.g. if the cell in Excel holds text and the field is set to integer you'll get an error

Comment: Yes, my excel data has one text column only and my access table has 2 columns (ID- Primary Key- which is number) and Field1(Short text)

Comment: How to set up the table depends on the content of the Excel file, and since I don't know it's content, I can't. What I can say is that with that structure and this code, you're trying to insert things in the primary key field, and that's probably why you're failing

Comment: As @Erik von Asmuth says, with your n = 0 for loop you're trying to populate the prime key with your text, remove the loop and just use fields(1) = ws.cells(i, 1)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I have implemented the above and its working seamlessly. Power to you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Excel to Access . . .

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

also if the path and excel name are fixed;  you can step thru the import manually using the External features from the ribbon - at the end of which will be a prompt to save those steps as a defined import.

you can then rerun the import just by a docmd to run the saved import